# Does the flow of a horizontal vector field invariate the differential of the projection?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M,N$ be compact manifolds with $M \stackrel{\pi}{\rightarrow} N$ a submersion. Suppose $V$ is a vector field with image in $\ker d \pi \subset TM $. I am trying to see whether $Lie_V (\pi^* \alpha) = 0$.

Denote by $\phi_t(x)$ the flow of $V$ at moment $t$ with initial condition $x \in M$. It's enough to see $Lie_V (\pi^* \alpha) = 0$ for $\alpha$ a $1$-form. Using the definition, I would have to see that $d_{\phi_t(x)} \pi ( d_x \phi_t(v)) = d_x \pi (v)$ for any $v \in T_xM$.

Essentially, I would have to see that $\pi \circ \phi_t = \pi$. I can't see how to use the hypothesis on $V$ to conclude this, though, or whether I can.

I know something similar holds for basic forms on a principal $G$-bundle (for $G$ a Lie group), and this is why I was hoping it would also hold here, but the proof from principal $G$-bundles can't be transported here.

Comment: It's a general fact that if you have a vector field on a manifold that is tangent to a closed submanifold, flows meeting that submanifold stay inside it at all times. Prove this and apply it to the fibers of $\pi$.

Comment: @Thorgott From what I understand, I can use the fact that $\ker d \pi$ is involutive, hence integrable, to see that around a point $x$ there's a submanifold $M'_x$ of $M$ whose tangent bundle is $\ker d \pi$. I can assume that $V_y \in M'_x$ for $y$ in some neighborhood of $x$, so for some small $t_y$ I have $\phi_{t_y}(y) \in M'_x$. If from these $t_y$'s I can obtain a uniform $t$, I would have that $\phi_t(y) \in M'_x$ which would show that $d_x \phi_t ( T_xM) \subset \ker d \pi$. This seems like more then expected, though.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're arguing, but it's more complicated than the fact I mention in my comment.

Comment: @Thorgott I understand what you mean now, I should just use the regular value theorem. But I'm struggling to prove why if a vector field is tangent to a closed submanifold, flows meeting the submanifold stay inside it at all times. It makes perfect sense intuitively but I just can't see how to rigorously relate the tangent vector at the point of intersection to the evolution of the flow. Could you give a hint?

Comment: 1. Your vector field restricted to the submanifold $S$ comes from a vector field on $S$. Since $S$ is a smooth manifold in its own right, this restricted vector field on $S$ has a local flow on $S$. This will agree with an appropriate restriction of the flow of the vector field on $M$, since both flows solve the same ODE. This shows if the flow is in $S$ at some point in time, it will be in $S$ for an open time interval around that point. 2. The closedness of $S$ makes the local statement 1. into a global statement. Assume the flow leaves $S$, derive a contradiction.